# package tikz error while drawing circuit

Tags: circuitikz

I was trying to draw the figure below. Please avoid the coordinates marked in this figure (:D)
[image]

My codes are

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4size]{article}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
  \draw 
        (0,0) -- ++ (2,0)
              -- ++ (0,1) to [nos,l=$y$] -- ++ (1,0)
              -- ++ (0,1) to [nos,l=$z$] -- ++ (2,0)
              -- ++ (0,-1) to (1,0) -- ++ (0,-1)
              ; 
    \end{circuitikz}
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which is just the above part of the above figure. But error are generating. `Package tikz Error: (, +, coordinate, pic, or node expected. -- ++ (0,1) to [nos,l=$y$] -` and so many.

What exactly are the mistakes?

Comment: does it look better now -- once you add a component in the circuit you need to finish the syntax line by a coordinate after the component -- `-- ++ (0,1) to [nos,l=$y$]++ (1,0)` -- after the `nos` component add the relevant coordinate `++(1,0)` without `dashes`

Comment: did the answer below meet your requirement -- if so please accept the answer and upvote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4size]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
  \draw 
        (0,0) -- ++ (2,0)
              -- ++ (0,1) to [nos,l=$y$]++ (1,0)
              -- ++ (0,1) to [nos,l=$z$]++ (2,0)
              -- ++ (0,-1) 
              -- ++ (1,0) 
              -- ++ (0,-1)
              -- ++ (1,0)
              ; 
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

**complete answer**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4size]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
 \begin{circuitikz}
  \draw 
        (0,0)   to [short, o-*]         ++ (2,0)        coordinate(in)
                -- ++ (0,1) 
                to [nos,l=$y$, -*]      ++ (2,0)        coordinate(y)
                -- ++ (0,0.5) 
                to [nos,l=$z$]          ++ (2,0)
                to [short,-*]           ++ (0,-0.5) 
                -| ++ (0.5,-1)                          coordinate(out)
                to[short,*-o]           ++(2,0)
        (y)     -- ++(0,-0.5)
                to [nos,l=$x$]          ++(2,0)               
                -- ++ (0,0.5)
        (in)    --++(0,-1)
                to[nos,l=$z$, -*]       ++(2,0)         coordinate(z)   
                -- ++ (0,0.5) 
                to [nos,l=$u$]          ++ (2,0)
                to [short,-*]           ++ (0,-0.5)             
        (z)     -- ++(0,-0.5)
                to [nos,l=$v$]          ++(2,0)               
                -- ++ (0,0.5)
                -|(out)
              ; 
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's very nice. Would you like to tell me what are `coordinate(in),  coordinate(out)`? Also why did you write `(y), (z)` separately?

Comment: since we use the notation `++` refers to `relative positioning` the actual coordinates are not known hence a temporary coordinate `in` stores the actual coordinate in memory and can be later recalled for further usage  -- as far as `y z` are concerned you can combine them if you so feel